# only one cell color should be change in row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i am working with datagridview in win forms now i have to change the color of cell when any user click on that cell i have to change that cell color to red for which i have use this code

```
 DataGridViewCellStyle CellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
 CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
 dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style = CellStyle;
```

but now if user has selected any other cell in same row then its color should be change to 
red and previous selected should make white again as non selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain a reference to the previously selected cell so you can change it back.

```
DataGridViewCell _currentCell = null; // class level variable

... 


// inside your event, set the current cell back to white
if(_currentCell != null) _currentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.White;

// now set the current cell to the selected cell
_currentCell = dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

_currentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: You need to create the variable 'CurrentCell'

Comment: what type of variable currentcell should it be of datagridviewcell type\

Comment: I think so... if you hover over "Rows" it should tell you the collection type. Hit F12 and go to definition, and it should tell you what type of objects the collection holds.